# In XML how to split a string into many substrings

Tags: xml

I have a string 223,23:50:45.
I want to extract 223 23 50 and 45 separately.
How to do it?
And also i would like to add a string to each of the sub string after they are extracted.

Answer (score 1):

### XML = structure

`XML` is a mark-up language to **describe and structure data**. You can do programming in `XML`.

### Programming language

Every programming language has function to manipulate string. Knowing that it should not be difficult to find a [split()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28string_functions%29#split)/[tokenize()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_tokenize.html) or similar function.

Manipulating `XML` is often done with `XSLT`, then you can use [`tokenize()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_tokenize.html):

```
<xsl:variable name="text">223,23:50:45</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value select="tokenize($text, '[,:]')" />
```